# Remove name of author from sidebar yet keep them in the bottom part of the presentation

Tags: beamer, sidebar

My name should not appear in the sidebar, but appear in the footer of the presentation or in the title page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useoutertheme{shadow} 
\usetheme{PaloAlto}
\title{The title}
\author{The Author}

\makeatletter
  \setbeamertemplate{sidebar \beamer@sidebarside}
  {
    \beamer@tempdim=\beamer@sidebarwidth%
    \advance\beamer@tempdim by -6pt%
    {\usebeamerfont{title in sidebar}%
      \vskip1.5em%
      \hskip3pt%
      \usebeamercolor[fg]{title in sidebar}%
      \insertshorttitle[width=\beamer@tempdim,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
      \vskip1.25em%
    }%
%    {%
%      \hskip3pt%
%      \usebeamercolor[fg]{author in sidebar}%
%      \usebeamerfont{author in sidebar}%
%      \insertshortauthor[width=\beamer@tempdim,center,respectlinebreaks]\par%
%      \vskip1.25em%
%    }%
    \insertverticalnavigation{\beamer@sidebarwidth}%
    \vfill
    \ifx\beamer@sidebarside\beamer@lefttext%
    \else%
      \usebeamercolor{normal text}%
      \llap{\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}\hskip0.1cm}%
      \vskip2pt%
    \fi%
  }%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\section{Section Test}
\begin{frame}{Frame title}
test
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```